# Why is Async function not being executed in python

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
intent=discord.Intents.default()
intent.members=True
client=discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild=client.get_guild(ServerID)
    channel=guild.get_channel(ChannelID)
    await channel.send(f'Welcome to the server{member.mention}! :D')
    await member.send(f'Welcome to the {guild.name} server,{member.name}! :D')
    print(f'Welcome to the {guild.name} server,{member.name}! :D')
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Why is my join function not being executed when someone joins my discord server ?
i have given all the permission as well that is needed to msg in the specific channel
but it seems that it never even calls the function
Edit: I changed it to on_member_join it still doesn't work

Comment: I think discord python is discontinued !

Comment: @httpanand idts cos i am onnly having issue with the join function  
rest all are working normally

Comment: Please read the docs for the library. The event isn't called "join".

Comment: @MohammadYusuf  ok . my friends who were using it , migrated to JS as dpy is no more maintained . Read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for more info .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for creating your client isn't complete. You have to assign the intents along with it, such as down below.

```py
client=discord.Client(intents = intent)
```

In fact, I would recommend you look at the [bot part of the discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) in order to setup the client with the necessary attributes for a discord bot.

(Also I'm going to assume you have the variables of ServerID and ChannelID saved somewhere else in the code, I just wanted to help the issue of triggering the on_member_join at all).

Answer (score 1):

`join` is an invalid event listener name in `discord.py`. Try changing the function's name to `on_member_join`.

Comment: heyy  i changed the thing it still  doesn't work